# appbar_scrolling_view_behavior not resolved at SwipeRefreshLayout databinding android

Tags: android-databinding, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, swiperefreshlayout, android-mvvm

I try to add the app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to the SwipeRefreshLayout but I don't know why i isn't resolved at XML layout although It works properly after running the codes. Does this matter with data binding and MVVM?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="ir.basamadazmanovin.heartrate.ui.main.home.HomeViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:onRefreshListener="@{()-> viewModel.onRefresehing()}"
            app:refreshing="@{viewModel.isLoading}">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_home_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                app:spanCount="3" />

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/fragment_home_toolbar"
                style="@style/Toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:subtitleTextColor="@color/material_white"
                app:title="@string/app_name"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/material_white" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
```

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" is red and the IDE mentions "Unresolved class '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior' less... (Ctrl+F1) Inspection info: Validates resource references inside Android XML files."

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

> ```
>             app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">
> ```